# How to find nth prime number in python without using function code?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I have no idea how to write a while loop to find nth prime number in python without using function code.

```
i=2
N=int(input("Enter a number:"))
count=0

while 


if (is prime number):
    count=count+1
    print("The prime number is:",str(i))
```

Comment: What do you mean by function code ?

Comment: @AlainT. like def()

Comment: You'll need a nested loop to determine if a number is prime.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.  Here's a naive one:

```
N = int(input("Enter N to get Nth prime: "))
count = 1
prime = 2
while count<N:                          # find more primes
    prime += 1 + prime%2                # next candidate (3,5,... odds)
    for divisor in range(3,prime,2):    # check if divisible
        if prime % divisor == 0: break  # not a prime, don't count it
    else:
        count += 1                      # didn't break, it's a prime

print(N,"th prime is ",prime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding Nth prime numbers using while loop

```
N=int(input("Enter a number:"))
count=0

i=2
cur_prime=0
while not count==N:
    j=2
    isPrime=True
    while j*j<=i:
        if i%j==0:
            isPrime=False
        j=j+1
    if isPrime==True:
        count=count+1
        cur_prime=i
    i=i+1

print(f"The {N}th prime number is {cur_prime}")

#Enter a number:5
#The 5th prime number is 11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input('Enter the number'))
for i in range(0, a):
   if a == a % 2 == 0 and =! 2:
      print("Prime number")
      break
else:
   print('not prime number')
break
```

Comment: `a == a % 2 == 0 and =! 2` is invalid code. also the last break is also invalid since it's not inside any loop and the whole code doesn't seem to "find nth prime number" as the question requests